# Different data size received from asset image in foreground and background in iOS 9.1?

Tags: ios, md5, alassetslibrary

I want to take backup of images on cloud so I calculate MD5 of an image in iOS.The issue is Md5 differs when it is calculated in foreground and background of the app. This issue come only in iOS 9.1. I use asset library to fetch the images. Below function is used to get the data (Both data are different from each when the application  is in foreground and in background)

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

CGImageRef imgRef = [assetRep fullScreenImage];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef
                                   scale:1.0f
                             orientation:(UIImageOrientation)assetRep.orientation];

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ALAssetRepresentation-MD5](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/ALAssetRepresentation-MD5) which calculates the md5 hash from an `ALAssetRepresentation` without creating a `UIImage` or using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. I assume that one of these `UIKit`-related steps is responsible for your issue, event though they should be thread-safe.